# Cannot find logging.json

Tags: nodeos

I cannot find logging.json. I am trying to find logging.json to increase the logging level but when I search for it in .local/share/eosio/nodeos/config where the [documentation](https://developers.eos.io/eosio-nodeos/docs/logging) says it will be, I cannot find it.

Any idea where it is or do I have to create it separately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the logging.json file does not exist already, it is probably using default logging. You can create logging.json in .local/share/eosio/nodeos/config and update it according to your needs.

For more details on what to put in logging.json, please check out **[this](https://developers.eos.io/eosio-nodeos/docs/logging)** documentation.